# Only in Moto G5 Plus: java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android

I need help in this code, The problem occurs only with th Moto G5 Plus.
When I run on other phones it works perfectly.

```
        try {
        FileInputStream fis;
        String caminho = arqUri.getPath();

        File file = new File(caminho);
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);

        skR1.setProgress((byte)fis.read());
        skR2.setProgress((byte)fis.read());
        skR3.setProgress((byte)fis.read());
        skR4.setProgress((byte)fis.read());

        fis.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("Artur", "Erro: "+e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Arquivo não encontrado!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Não foi possível abrir o arquivo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The logcat:

> 04-17 10:10:39.840 9775-9775/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
>   04-17 10:10:40.071 9775-9775/com.redline_efi.redlinewifiBeta I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
>   04-17 10:10:40.137 9775-9775/com.redline_efi.redlinewifiBeta W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
>   04-17 10:10:40.312 9775-9775/com.redline_efi.redlinewifiBeta W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /media/Telegram/Telegram Documents/1_5147931815117324292.rlc (No such file or directory)
>   04-17 10:10:40.317 9775-9775/com.redline_efi.redlinewifiBeta W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>   04-17 10:10:40.317 9775-9775/com.redline_efi.redlinewifiBeta W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:146)
>   04-17 10:10:40.317 9775-9775/com.redline_efi.redlinewifiBeta W/System.err:     at com.redline_efi.redlinewifi.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:172)
>   04-17 10:10:40.317 9775-9775/com.redline_efi.redlinewifiBeta W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672)
>   04-17 10:10:40.317 9775-9775/com.redline_efi.redlinewifiBeta W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
>   04-17 10:10:40.317 9775-9775/com.redline_efi.redlinewifiBeta W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
>   04-17 10:10:40.317 9775-9775/com.redline_efi.redlinewifiBeta W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
>   04-17 10:10:40.317 9775-9775/com.redline_efi.redlinewifiBeta W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>   04-17 10:10:40.317 9775-9775/com.redline_efi.redlinewifiBeta W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
>   04-17 10:10:40.317 9775-9775/com.redline_efi.redlinewifiBeta W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   04-17 10:10:40.317 9775-9775/com.redline_efi.redlinewifiBeta W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>   04-17 10:10:40.317 9775-9775/com.redline_efi.redlinewifiBeta W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
>   04-17 10:10:40.317 9775-9775/com.redline_efi.redlinewifiBeta W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   04-17 10:10:40.317 9775-9775/com.redline_efi.redlinewifiBeta W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>   04-17 10:10:40.317 9775-9775/com.redline_efi.redlinewifiBeta W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)

Comment: perhaps you should add drive information to `caminho`, giving it the fully qualifying path

Comment: I try "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+caminho", same error.

Comment: Do you have permissions to read storage?

Comment: Yes, This same apk works on previous versions of the android. 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: The problem just got worse. It's working on a friend's phone, a Samsung S7, mine is a Moto G5 Plus.

Comment: Your code cannot run on any phone as a path that starts with /file does not exist. Nowhere.

Comment: Please edit your post to use a possible path. Then check with file.exists() if the file exists. Add that code to your post. Report the results.

Comment: greenapps, This path is the result of my debug on my phone. This path is received from an Intent. The file exists on the phone you are running on. I put in the above code just to exemplify. I do not think this code contains any errors, since it is working on any phone except my own.

Comment: Please paste the logcat error

Comment: Tested on S8, the same app and works.